# Como que faço uma quebra de linha entre dois labels

Tags: javascript

Olá, nao estou conseguindo fazer uma quebra de linha entre dois labels poderiam me explicar como posso fazer isso. Obrigado.

```
    <label style="display: table-cell inline-block; padding: 0 4px 0 6px">Nome:</label>
<span>
    <input id="nome" type="text" style="display: inline-block table-cell; padding: 0 4 px 0 6 px;">
</span>

<label>Data de nascimento: </label>
<span>
    <input id="data" type="date">
</span>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só pra constar, quebra de linha em HTML é `<br>`  (br = break, ou seja, quebra). Não necessariamente seja o melhor para o seu caso, mas convém saber que existe.

Answer (score 1):

Fala amigo, tudo bem?
Então , não sei porque você acabou envolvendo esse input com span, não tem necessidade.

Uma forma simples de resolver seu problema com a estrutura de html é envolvendo seus inputs com divs diferentes, que por padão já são *display:block* e vão ocupar toda a linha, fazendo que cada div fique em uma linha.

**dessa forma:**

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <label>Nome:</label>
  <input id="nome" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Data de nascimento: </label>
  <input id="data" type="date">
</div>
```

Tem outras formas de resolver isso com css, porem acho que essa é a forma mais simples.

espero ter ajudado.
abraço